# ¿Cómo usar un Spinner en RecyclerView?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, recyclerview, spinner, android-spinner

que tal (:

Durante los ultimos días he estado lidiando con lo siguiente:
Quiero un implementar un Spinner dentro de una serie de recyclerView que a su vez se encuentra en un fragment. El problema es que tengo problemas a llamar al agregar un recyclerview dentro del fragment y no encuentro la forma de pasar el parametro al spinner

**Esta es mi clase fragment.kt**

```
class fragHer(var nCalif: Int) : Fragment() {


var spGerente: Spinner?=null
lateinit var sp_ca:Spinner
lateinit var prefs: SharedPreferences
lateinit var editor: SharedPreferences.Editor
var califList= ArrayList<Porcentaje>()
var lista:RecyclerView?= null
lateinit var adaptador: porcentajeAdapter
var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager?=null



override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    var vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag_her, container, false)
    val context = vista.context

    prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Herramientas", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
   

    initData()

    //findViews
    lista = vista.findViewById(R.id.rv_pAsesor)
    sp_ca = vista.findViewById(R.id.sp_ca)


    //RV
    lista?.setHasFixedSize(true)
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    lista?.layoutManager = layoutManager
    adaptador = porcentajeAdapter(context, califList, nCalif)


    return vista




}

private fun initData() {
    califList.add(Porcentaje(sp_ca))

}}
```

**Este es el modelo**

```
import android.widget.Spinner

class Porcentaje (var porcent: Spinner)
```

**Este es el mi adaptador**

```
class porcentajeAdapter(private var mContext: Context, items:ArrayList<Porcentaje>,  var numCalif: Int): RecyclerView.Adapter<porcentajeAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


lateinit var prefs: SharedPreferences
lateinit var editor: SharedPreferences.Editor
var items: ArrayList<Porcentaje>?=null

init {
    this.items = items
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): porcentajeAdapter.ViewHolder {
    val vista = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.rv_spinner, parent, false)
    val viewHolder = ViewHolder(vista)

    return viewHolder
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: porcentajeAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = items?.get(position)
    val posicion = position
    holder.spinner = item?.porcent


override fun getItemCount(): Int {
   return  items?.count()!!
}

class ViewHolder(vista: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(vista){
    var vista = vista
    var spinner: Spinner? = null


    init {
        spinner = vista.findViewById(R.id.sp_ca)
    }
}
```

Quisiera saber si alguien ha implementado un spinner dentro de un recyclerview y me pudiera dar un consejo de como implementarlo correctamente, ya que me tiene loco esto. Me sería de mucha ayuda.

Muchas gracias (:

Answer (score 0):

Me cuesta entender un poco porque lo armas de esa manera, la que me funciona a mi es tener en una variable el stringArray que son los valores que pasas al spinner
Ej.

```
    val contenidoSpinner = arrayOf("1","2","3","4") // a esta variable tenes que pasarle 
    los porcentajes que va a cargar el spinner en un array
    val spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner)// buscas el ID de tu spinner
        if (spinner != null) {
            val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, contenidoSpinner)
            spinner.adapter = adapter
        }
```

Ojala te sirva.